# Gradle failing to resolve local .arr dependencies in my libs folder

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I have 2 local dependencies in my libs folder, somehow gradle is failing to resolve them,
this is my settings.gradle file;

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "eADAPP"
include ':app'
```

and my build.gradle file app level;

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation name: 'FacePassAndroidSDK-McvSafe-release', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mcvSafe.v1.2.2', ext: 'aar'
}
```

can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you use 'mavenLocal'

briefly...

```
1. add to repository 'mavenLocal'
2. add 'New Module' for local lib publishing
3. move local lib to 'New Module'
4. make of 'New Module' build.gradle
ex>
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.local.libs'
    compileSdk 32
}

publishing {
    publications {
        appLibs1 (MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'FacePassAndroidSDK'
            artifactId = 'FacePassAndroidSDK-McvSafe-release'
            version = '0.0.1'

            artifact './{New Module Path}/FacePassAndroidSDK-McvSafe-release.aar'
        }
        ....
```